# Connection refused sockets. Normal behavior?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I have a socket server which accepts multiple connections from various clients. I'm testing it on localhost with a client application which connects - sends data and closes connection 10 times every 10 ms. Some times the test client raises an error: Connection refused by the remote server or something similar.
Is this a normal behavior of the server application ?

Answer (score 2):

10 connects every 10mS is one connection per millisecond, which seems a rather fast rate.   Are these connection attempts being made in parallel?  If so, perhaps you are filling up the server's listen() backlog-queue; IIRC clients who try to connect while the backlog-queue is full will get a connection-refused error.

To test that hypothesis, try passing in larger or smaller numbers as the second argument to listen() on your server, and see if that makes the connection-refused error occur more or less often.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Jeremy.  You didn't mention the protocol, but I assume it's SOCK_STREAM.  It will take longer than 10ms to do the tcp handshake on anything but the most local connection, eventually causing a backlog (and subsequent connection refused error) no matter how high you set your listen backlog to.

You'd be way ahead if you could keep the connection open, and not close it down during each of your computation cycles.